# Как понять что можно приступать к фрилансу

Tags: веб-программирование

Занимаюсь разработкой сайтов уже 4 года (с 10 лет). Да, согласен возраст мой ещё не большой, но ещё 4 года писать сайты которые нужны мне, уже так сказать не в радость.  Как мне понять что я уже готов к фрилансу и как ко мне будут относиться люди которым будут нужны сайты.

Comment: @NetSperes, Вы уверены, что действительно хотите, вот прямо сейчас, зарабатывать деньги программированием?

Учтите, если подходить серьезно, то это требует кучу времени.

Comment: Я конечно сам еще новичок, но судя по твоим вопросам на этом сайте, автор, тебе еще учиться и учиться. Странно вообще, что за 4 года ты не особо далеко ушел. Хотя, может возраст сказывается. Но все равно удачи.

Comment: > Странно вообще, что за 4 года ты не особо далеко ушел.

хм, возможно просто наставника нету, или он недостаточно хорош :)

Comment: @avp, а чем мне сервера оплачивать моих "проектов"  деньгами с обедов?

Comment: @NetSperes если серьезные проекты - то финансирование должно быть, а так, для себя - бесплатные хостинги :)

Comment: Ну, а если я пишу онлайн бот для игр? То что мне на фри хост вставать.

Comment: @NetSperes, так может дешевле/проще/интереснее поднять сервер на своём компе?  
Если что попроще, то можно и вовсе взять какой-то шаред-хостинг за копейки.

Comment: На компе? У меня нетбук. И интернет через телефон(врубаю точку доступа ну телефон/ модем и ловлю WIFI с нет бука)

Comment: @NetSperes ну так родители же есть. Что, не дадут 2-3 тыщи рублей на хостинг?

Comment: > 2-3 тыщи рублей в месяц на хостинг

60 долларов в месяц за хостинг?, что-то много

Comment: @danpetruk нет не дадут

Comment: Самый лучший способ - сходить к гадалке.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Боюсь, что они будут относиться к вам так, как и стоит этого ожидать - то есть как к ребенку. А это значит что:

1. Даже если вы хороший специалист, это придется доказывать вдвойне
2. Многие не захотят иметь дело исключительно из пренебрежительных соображений - дескать, вот еще, не хватало мне школьнику отдавать делать сайт
3. Люди будут делать скидку на то,что вы можете быть в силу возраста несамостоятельны в решениях. Зависеть от этого вряд ли кто-то захочет
4. Многие будут  считать (и даже хотеть), что вас легко обмануть
5. В силу возраста и отсутствия серьезной практики у вас скорее всего не до конца сформированные и не слишком правильные представления о разработке (и уж тем более проектировании) сайтов и веб-приложений

Впрочем, все не так пессимистично - если у вас к вашему юному возрасту уже есть какая-то теоретическая и практическая база, это уже неплохо. А деньги и опыт от вас не убегут

Comment: Не обязательно выставлять свой истинный возраст, есть много фрилансеров с достаточно высоким рейтингом и котиками на аватарках + "Super-site Master" вместо имени и фамилии.
Я вот для себя отлично уяснил что возраст - это совсем не показатель. Встречал как 14 летних пацанов, которые были гораздо эрудированее меня в общем, и профессиональнее в некоторых вопросах в частности, так и 30 летних людей, которых кроме как "придурками" никак не назвать.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы посоветовал бы тебе найти некого "наставника", человека который уже достаточно давно занимается программированием, с большим опытом. Он поможет лучше ориентироваться :) Так же, к примеру с ним вместе мог бы и фрилансить, получишь дополнительные навыки - командная разработка :)

> Как мне понять что я уже готов к фрилансу

Начинаешь с маленького, накапливаешь портфолио, свои работы, положительные отзывы, чтобы заказчики видели на что ты способен :)

Comment: А вот в этом совете (пойти в подмастерья) что-то разумное есть.

Самое сложное, конечно, в деталях - найти "наставника", который согласится сотрудничать и при этом сможет чему-то научить.

Comment: А где найти "наставника"?
Я не уверен что кому то  станет интересно разговаривать со школьником.

Comment: извините ,у вас цель сейчас научиться программировать или во что бы то ни стало зарабатывать деньги? Если первое - то нет проблем- учитесь, времени у вас навалом. если второе, то посоветовать что-то в рамках закона 14-летнему подростку в этом плане сложно

Comment: > А где найти "наставника"?

это делается хитро - гуляешь по форумам программистов к примеру, сдруживаешься с каким нибудь программистом, который на твой взгляд сможет чему нибудь научить, и ненавязчиво просишь сначало в одном разобраться, потом в другом, потом просишь к примеру помочь проект свой сделать (к примеру на фрилансе), если правильно подружился, то не откажет :)

Comment: > Я не уверен что кому то станет интересно разговаривать со школьником.

обычно, лень становится иногда монотонную работу выполнять, или писать простые программки (их просто не интересно писать), так что делать, если программка нужна, Говоришь ученику, напиши то и то, что не понятно, спрашивай ))) ну в общем один учит хитростям, а другой пишет мелочи

Answer (score 4):

Здравствуйте. Советую вам поискать заказы среди своих знакомых и друзей, их родителей.
Создав сайт для одного из них, вы получите:

- первый **опыт** общения с заказчиком
- первые реальные **деньги** за свою работу
- **рекламу** (если вы заранее создадите
     сайт-визитку, а в футере сайта
     заказчика поставите небольшой баннер
     или ссылку на визитку)

Таким образом вы создадите себе портфолио, с которым можно смело идти на фриланс-сайты.
Если вы действительно создаете хорошие сайты со вкусом, то бояться нечего. Удачи вам и вашим проектам!

Comment: Искал,ни кому не надо. Хотя нет, я делал для школьного сайта. В начале директор попросил сделать. Но потом... Просто сказал что ему это не нужно

Comment: > среди своих знакомых и друзей, их родителей

я стараюсь максимально от таких отградиться, т.к.:

- они хотят как можно лучше
- они хотят как можно меньше заплатить
- они думают если сделал сайт, то ты должен его поддерживать
- они думают что все что они хотят это жутко просто

и много друго, это из серии "**Почему программист не таксист**"

Comment: @IVsevolod, но так почти с каждым заказчиком, нет? Проблема друзей-знакомых больше в том, что с ними можно поссориться

Comment: @xEdelweiss для меня проблема в том, что трудно отказать )

Comment: @IVsevolod, поэтому и трудно отказать

Comment: >Искал,ни кому не надо. Хотя нет, я делал для школьного сайта. В начале директор попросил сделать. Но потом... Просто сказал что ему это не нужно
Ну м"№*; директор. А во фрилансе всё то же будет.

>Создав сайт для одного из них...
Да для начала даже не сайт, а хотя бы скрипт какой-нибудь "в вёрде". Слушай, что люди говорят и на что жалуются. Просто опыт делового общения - полезная штука, всякие нюансы "он думал, что я бесплатно сделаю", "у меня это столько-то времени займёт, а получу столько-то"...

Answer (score 3):

Только попробовать.
А вообще понятие готов- не готов очень относительное. Я сам кучу горе-"специалистов" повидал, так было такое чувство что они вообще тему задания изучают во время выполнения задания, но тем не менее это не мешало им представляться как "высококвалифицированными профессионалами".

Comment: Ну, можно попробовать обложаться и ...

Comment: ..получить стимул к улучшению :)
Стоит посмотреть и понять, что взялся за изучение js 4 дня назад, а про php прочитал пару статеек(это его слова). Все-таки с таким уровнем, наверное, не стоит браться за заказы и подводить людей.

Comment: Ну не 4 дня назад (год) Просто не во всём разбираюсь, а если бы я сказал что год то меня бы засмеяли как было на киберфоруме

Comment: тогда напрочь забудьте пока что о деньгах и фрилансе и, как говорил вождь мирового пролетариата, учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться. Не хочу вас разочаровывать, но дин год знакомства с JS и пара статей по php - это вообще ничто.

Comment: Всем когда-то приходилось начинать... Лучший вариант, по-моему, сделать не сложный сайтик за небольшие деньги (1000 р. допустим), тому кто никуда не спешит. Но найти такого клиента очень сложно...

Answer (score 0):

Зачем пугаете человека? Возрастом никто интересоваться не будет. Заказчикам интересен только опыт работы. Если такого опыта мало, то можно начать с низкооплачиваемых заданий или узкоспециализированных, где конкуренция ниже.
В любом случае стоит попробовать, чтобы понять для себя - подходит это или нет.
Автору вопроса большое уважение, если готов в 14 лет самостоятельно зарабатывать.

Comment: почитайте второй комментарий к ответу пользователя @Артур Пантелеев. Он многое проясняет